# Change the redirection URL of the "support" button in the header

Tags: newmips

I need to change the URL of the support button which appears when you click on the connection on right of the top banner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the editor and edit file in: views > main_layout.dust

Find block with class "user-body" (in my case, it's on line 73) and edit href links to match your expectations

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://newmips.com/contact">{@__ key="navbar.support"/}</a>
```